# sharepoint 2013 wcf issue

Tags: wcf, sharepoint-2013, unauthorized

After upgrade to SharePoint 2013 my wcf stop working - I can access to svc file through browser or svcutil.exe, but not from silverlight client - when client call service the logon window appears,why? So at the end I have 401 unauthorized error.

In SP I use claims-based authentication and on web.config of service I have next code

```
    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
    </security>
```

Comment: Is your silverlight application hosted on same sharepoint server?

Comment: I think this happens because SharePoint 2013 uses claims based identity and before calling wcf service you need to get windows identity from claims and impersonate it. Check this post http://blah.winsmarts.com/2013-11-Use_C2WTS_to_get_a_classic_windows_identity_from_a_claims_identity.aspx

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets thanks! Yes, it's because of claims-based identity. I had a little time to restore my site, so I had to return to Windows authentication and service started to work fine. I've read that article, so unfortunatly I need to rewrite my service code. Anyway, thanks for your help!